# Non-standard sorting of the ls output

Tags: ls, sort, output

I usually include a date in the filename so that files and directories are listed in chronological order when I use the `ls` command, e.g. `2015-08-29_letter_to_santa.txt`.

A drawback is that tab-completion is hampered. For the example above, if I want to open the letter to santa, I first need to get through the date before I can swiftly tab-complete the rest of the filename. This is annoying when many filenames start with a date.

I would like to be able to name the file something like `letter_to_santa.2015-08-29.txt` but still have `ls` output the files sorted by the date appearing in the filename. Any ideas of how to accomplish this, and at the same time preserving the colourful output that `ls` produces?

For the sake of being specific, let's assume that a filename is on the format `basename.date.extension` and `.` is used exactly twice in the filename.

Comment: Out of curiosity, doesn't `ls -clt` do what you want without embedding the timestamp in the filename?

Comment: ...knowing that if you change `ls`'s behavior for these filenames, it will also change them for files that don't have that filename format...

Comment: @Andy - not if one ever changes the inode (e.g. with `chmod`).  Or perhaps the dates aren't creation dates, but the date of the subject matter?  That's something I do, so I might today write an article about last year's summer holiday, and I'd use the date of the holiday to help me find it later.

Comment: @Andy - The date in the filename is arbitrary and independent of ctime, mtime or atime, like Toby suggested.

Comment: If you are using bash you can type `*santa` and then ask for glob-complete-word with escape-g, so you dont need to type the start of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 ls | sort -t. -k2 | while read f
 do
    ls "$f"
 done
```

I am assuming you have plain ordinary unix file without funny char in name.

Comment: In fact, doing just `ls -lF | sort -t. -k2` almost does it (the way I want it). It even preserves the colours. The niggly bits are 1. directories are mixed with regular files (I would like all directories to be listed first, sorted according to "-t. -k2" as well), 2. the line "total x" shows, and 3. filenames without a `.` seem to appear in arbitrary order (would be nice if they came in alphabetical order) and filenames on the format `basename.extension` are sorted according to extension and not its full filename. I know, I didn't ask for any of this in the original question. :)

Comment: Extra -k will help, I ll see tomorrow.